# SqlCeDatareader.HasRows raising exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, datareader

[image]

How to solve the issue?

OR is there any other way to check if the result contains any records?(except rdr.Read() method)

btw I am using Sqlserver Compact 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "except `rdr.Read()` method" but that feels like the most natural approach to me.

Call `Read()`, and if it returns true, populate the result, otherwise set the result to null.

Also note that

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

is generally an abomination which should be removed. I would also question a design and implementation which:

- Ignored naming conventions (`getSites`)
- Used a `bool` return value but always returned true, and an `out` parameter for the real results
- Didn't dispose of the command itself
- Declared the `rdr` method way before it's needed, for no obvious reason. (It's not going to be *useful* outside the `using` statement anyway, so why not declare it there?)

Comment: If you dont call Read, you wont even get the first row's data, so I am not sure what the OP is after :S

Comment: actually .Read moves the record one step further, so I am going to miss first record.. and thank you for design related suggestions.. :)

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: So just call the extension method unconditionally, and you'll get no results back if there were no rows.

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: It is at `-1` initially.